# OpenCV mat element access speed difference

Tags: c++, performance, opencv

I am trying to benchmark the performance of different ways to access OpenCV mat element. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.9.3 and -O3 flag with the latest OpenCV in the trunk.

The first one is using at.

```
cv::Mat test = cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC1);

for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
        test.at<uchar>(i,j) = rand();
      }
    }
```

The second one is using ptr.

```
cv::Mat test = cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC1);

for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
        a.ptr<uchar>(i)[j] = rand();
      }
    }
```

The third one is using ptr with a intermediate variable.

```
cv::Mat test = cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC1);

for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){

      uchar* inter = test.ptr<uchar>(i);

      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
        inter[j] = rand();
      }
    }
```

The first and second one both gives me 5000ms on average in 10 tries, and the third one gives me 4800ms on average in 10 tries.

Why is the first one performing the same as second one? Shouldn't the first one be slower because of the extra boundary checks by at?

Why is the third one performing 4% faster than the second one? Shouldn't the performance be identical?

Comment: I think you are testing rand() and not Mat access. You should add example <br>       uchar* inter = test.ptr<uchar>(i);

      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++,inter++){
        *inter = i;

Comment: .at has boundary checks only in debug mode. release mode is quite fast.

Comment: the last one is faster because there is a difference whether you have to compute 1 or 2 sums for each address-computation. test.ptr basixally computes "address + i * widthstep" and inter[j] computes "inter + j * pixelsize"

Comment: @Micka If that's the reason I am so surprised that the compiler cannot optimize it out... Time to change all my code. If you write an answer I will accept it

Comment: I'll wait, maybe someone can confirm it or has a better reason :D